# Problems invoking View Component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Im working on my first asp.net core project, and therefore also my first view component. I thought I had followed every step in the tutorials, but I cant successfully invoke my view componenent.

Here's my code:

**/ViewComponents/ItemListViewComponent.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace LC.CompuTECH._2017.ViewComponents
{
    public class ItemListViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public ItemListViewComponent(string t)
        {
            switch (t.ToUpper())
            {
                case "STUDENT":
                    this.Type = ListTypes.Student;
                    break;

                case "WORK":
                    this.Type = ListTypes.Work;
                    break;

                case "GAMER":
                    this.Type = ListTypes.Gamer;
                    break;

                case "OTHER":
                    this.Type = ListTypes.Other;
                    break;
            }
        }

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ListTypes Type { get; internal set; }

        public enum ListTypes
        {
            Student,
            Work,
            Gamer,
            Other
        }
    }
}
```

**/Views/Shared/Components/ItemList/Default.cshtml**

```
MY VIEW COMPONENT
```

and I try to invoke like this:

```
@await  Component.InvokeAsync("ItemList", new { t = "student" })
```

but I only get:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'LC.CompuTECH._2017.ViewComponents.ItemListViewComponent'.

This should be so basic so I cant figure out what Im doing wrong.

Any help will be highly highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your constructor should only take things that can be injected, ie dependencies of your component.

Whatever you want to pass in goes into the invoke method, not the constructor

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace LC.CompuTECH._2017.ViewComponents
{
    public class ItemListViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public ItemListViewComponent()
        {

        }

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string t)
        {
            switch (t.ToUpper())
            {
                case "STUDENT":
                    this.Type = ListTypes.Student;
                    break;

                case "WORK":
                    this.Type = ListTypes.Work;
                    break;

                case "GAMER":
                    this.Type = ListTypes.Gamer;
                    break;

                case "OTHER":
                    this.Type = ListTypes.Other;
                    break;
            }

            return View();
        }

        public ListTypes Type { get; internal set; }

        public enum ListTypes
        {
            Student,
            Work,
            Gamer,
            Other
        }
    }
}
```

note also that unless you have something to await you use Invoke not InvokeAsync, if you use InvokeAsync then your method signature should be

```
Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string t)
```

and inside that method you await something ie a call to a service

Comment: Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string t) did the job!